# In System Verilog, how to determine whether a class item exists?

Tags: system-verilog

I have a system with a config file that is read in by the testbench.  The config file is generated by another group and it now has config values that are no longer used, but which they do not want to remove.  In the testbench, I read in the config file and apply the values in it to a member of a multiply-nested class that represents the register map of the device.

Up to this point, I had a large but simple case statement that parsed the config key, then simply applied the associated value to the register field that was associated with the configuration key.  E.g.,

```
while(!$feof(cfg_file)) begin
  cfg_r        = $fgets(cfg_line, cfg_file);
  cfg_r        = $sscanf(cfg_line,"%s = %s", cfg_name_str, cfg_value_str);

  case (cfg_name_str)

    "gpe" : begin
       ewd_regs.op.gpe.coef = cfg_field_value;
    end

    // Other configuration keywords and a default:

  endcase
end
```

In this example the keyword and the register field are both "gpe", but for several of the fields the config file keyword and the register field are different.

Now with the clutter in the config file I have some keywords that are listed in the config file and which match one of the cases, but which are no longer defined by separate code that defines and builds the register/field map.  So, in the above example, ewd_regs.op exists, but ewd_regs.op.gpe does not.

So my question is, how can I test to determine whether ewd_regs.op.gpe exists before doing the assignment?  If it does not exist, I want to log the condition and continue parsing the config file.

Comment: If `ewd_regs.op.gpe` doesn't exist, your code won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way within the SystemVerilog Language to lookup an identifier using a string to see if it exists and then use that string to access it.

If this is a UVM register model, they have implemented an associated string to class handle lookup that you could use instead of direct handle names.

Otherwise, you may want to create a script that reads the config file and generates this portion of your testbench file.

Comment: I feared that might be the case. It is UVM-ish, but the person who wrote all that is no longer with the company, so if I will need to dig into it or write some python to write System Verilog or give up on having one codebase that handles multiple generations of config files.